# SQL query for Rails Scope, Disjoint?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, scopes

I am trying to find the **total count** of **fruits** that belong to a **supermarket** that do not have associated **Items** records.

My relationship is: Supermarkets has_many fruits and Supermarkets has_many items. Items are linked to fruits by their external_upc code. How can I find the amount of records in the  fruits table for a given supermarket that don't have a corresponding entry in items?

I am not sure where to start with this query, I am thinking I need either a Left Join or a NOT IN for my where clause. But help would be appreciated.

Comment: I other words: I basically need to select all the items for a supermarket, and all the fruits for the same supermarket and ask, "how many fruits are not in the list of items". I am guessing an except clause could perhaps help as well.

Answer (score 0):

Without more information I am going to guess a couple of things, but a possible solution could be:

```
supermarket.fruits.where(external_upc: nil).count
```

`'supermarket'` is the object that represents the Supermarket which you want to search by, so `'supermarket.fruits'` will give you all the fruits in that market.

Then, I am assuming that if a fruit doesn't have an item linked it is going to have their external_upc code to nil, so `'where(external_upc: nil)'` will give you the fruits (which are in your supermarket) that doesn't have an item linked.

Finally we use `'.count'` to ... count.

Comment: One of the problems is, the fruit was originally created from the item, and so they do have a upc_code, except some of the original items that were used to create the fruit. no longer exist. 

I know there are some outlying problem with these relationships but that is beyind the scope of this question..

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find what I was looking for by using an EXCEPT query.

```
Select COUNT(item_id)
FROM (
SELECT item_id
FROM fruits
WHERE fruits.active = 't' AND fruits.supermarket_id = 2
EXCEPT
SELECT externa;_upc
FROM items) f;
```